# Display images from urls in a carousel from Firebase + Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to develop a webpage which has an image carousel (from the Materialize framework) that displays a series of images from urls fetched from Firebase. To account for varying numbers of images I'm using Angular.js. Right now my HTML code for that section looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="GalleryController as galleryImages">
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider grey" data-indicators="true">
            <div ng-repeat="image in galleryImages.images">
              <a class="carousel-item"><img ng-src="{{image}}"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('GalleryController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var galleryImages = this;

    getData(function(data) {
        galleryImages.images = data["gallery"];
        $scope.$apply();
    });
}]);

function getData(completion) {
  var database = firebase.database();
  var ref = database.ref('nodes/myNode');
  ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    completion(snapshot.val());
  });
}
```

Where `data["gallery"]` is an array of image urls. Something to note is that if I insert a line like `galleryImages.images = ["some image url here"]` after `var galleryImages = this`, then it actually displays that image. But if I put the same line inside `getData`, then it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** tried using AngularFire. No success yet. Here's my new code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="GalleryController">
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider grey" data-indicators="true">
            <div ng-repeat="image in object.gallery">
                <a class="carousel-item" href="#one"><img ng-src="{{image}}"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on the Javascript end:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);
app.controller('GalleryController', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    var data = $firebaseObject(firebase.database().ref('nodes/myNode'));
    data.$loaded().then(function() {
        $scope.data = data;

        var object = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key) { object[key] = value; });

        $scope.object = object;
   });
}]);
```

Printing out `object` indicates it actually does have a value for the key `gallery`, which is an array of urls. But the images still aren't displaying in the carousel.

Comment: show the `getData` function

Comment: Updated the question with getData code.

Comment: Could you use `var galleryImages = this.images;`. This looks like a scoping issue

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but `galleryImages` isn't actually the list of images - it's the object for the controller? `galleryImages.images` is the list of images.

Comment: You can use angularfire which  is the officially supported AngularJS binding for Firebase. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire. Why are you calling getData function outside the scope of angular?

Comment: Tried using AngularFire, still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the materialize myself with JavaScript and various API calls. I found that when waiting for a response from an API call, js goes ahead and runs the rest of the code anyways. Often times, the js that is responsible for interactive elements such as carousels loads before the API gives a response.

I simply use the setTimeout(function, time) function to run the js code responsible for loading the interactive content with a delay. I would say 2000ms is a healthy delay.

I know that carousels in materialize are initiated with `$('.carousel').carousel();`, so we can put that in a function and at the very bottom of a page, use the setTimeout() function to call carousel after 2 seconds.

**Put this after firebase and angular code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(initiateSlider, 2000)
});

function initiateSlider() {
  $('.carousel').carousel();
}
```

After 2 seconds, the API call should have been handled so the website can load properly.